# Less redundant way of if else statement

Tags: python

I have code that's an if else statement. It does x if some variable is True, and if it isn't then it does basically the same code block, but with one minor difference. The code block is really big, and it looks extremely redundant and ugly to do two of the same huge code blocks with a minor tweak. Is there any way to avoid doing this? Basically, the only difference is if the variable it looks at is True then it calls a function on an integer to encode it. Here's my code:

```
for dependency in resource.dependencies:
    if (
        resource.header.compression_flags
        & compression_flag.CompressionFlag.use_compressed_integers
    ):
        bytedata = bytedata.replace(
            guid.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder="big")
            + varint.encode(int(dependency[1:])),
            sha1_hash.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder="big")
            + bytes.fromhex(image_hash),
        )
    else:
        bytedata = bytedata.replace(
            guid.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder="big")
            + int(dependency[1:]).to_bytes(length=4, byteorder="big"),
            sha1_hash.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder="big")
            + bytes.fromhex(image_hash),
        )
```

Comment: Write a function that takes the "tweak" as an argument, and call it from the branches of the `if` statement.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (_i.e._ regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the redundant code before the if else block and just the difference inside the block itself.

```
if var:
    # minor difference
else:
    # other code
```

Please provide more inputs about the question for a precise answer.

Edit:

```
for dependency in resource.dependencies:
    if (resource.header.compression_flags
    & compression_flag.CompressionFlag.use_compressed_integers):
        enc=varint.encode(int(dependency[1:]))
    else:
        enc=int(dependency[1:]).to_bytes(length=4, byteorder="big")

    bytedata = bytedata.replace(
        guid.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder="big")
        + enc,
        sha1_hash.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder="big")
        + bytes.fromhex(image_hash),
    )
```

Comment: Please use proper Python comments for Python code answers.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You've posted code now and Sneha's answer is exactly what I'd do.

---

It's hard to see exactly what you are trying to do without posting source code (at least post a generic example if it contains something sensitive). That being said, you could do two things:

1. Put the if-else in multiple locations throughout this large code block to change behavior accordingly.

   ```
   # common code here
   # more code

   if x:
       # do something
   else:
       # something else

   # common code here
   # more code

   if x:
       # do something
   else:
       # something else

   # common code here
   # more code
   ```
2. Turn the large code block into a function that accepts and argument to change its behavior.

   ```
   x = True
   my_function(x)
   ```

Comment: They edited the question 6 minutes ago to add the code.